# How do I create a new build definition in TFS 2017 across projects

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We just upgraded from TFS 2013 to TFS 2017 and I was excited to go in and create a new build definition, but I can't seem to do it at the collection level. I can only create a new build definition once I've selected a project and then when defining the Get Sources page I can't seem to access other projects within the collection. The highest level it will allow me to get is the current project. In the Repository drop-down the only option is the current project. How can I create a new build definition across projects in TFS 2017?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TFS build is project level for now, it's not able to create a build definition at collection level and across projects.  For 2015 you could, instead of using the trigger path `'$/{team project}'`, also insert just `'$/'`, which would result in that the continuous integration build triggers on all check-ins in that team project collection. It's more like a backdoor.

However, In TFS 2017, it 's no longer possible to freely edit this field, and that you can only add a trigger for the team project that the build definition resides in.

---

There had been a uservoice and got **started**:

> **VSO build vnext: share build templates between projects**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/8468566-vso-build-vnext-share-build-templates-between-pro

As a workaround you could export your existing build definition in the project to other project. However, this just avoid you manually duplicating the definition in another team project. It's not able to get source from another project which different with the build definition belongs to.

There is an [Export/Import Build Definition](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onlyutkarsh.ExportImportBuildDefinition) extension in Visual Studio Marketplace you can use now.  Also available from within the TFS2017 update1 Build Definitions web UI:

[image: See screenshot here].

Comment: Thanks (I guess ). That's disappointing. I could swear that this was possible in TFS 2015, but I guess not now.

Comment: I just checked out the link and I'm not sure that describes my problem. What I need had nothing to do with templates.

Comment: @Ben_G Understood, For 2015 you could, instead of using the trigger path '$/{team project}', also insert just '$/', which would result in that the continuous integration build triggers on all checkins in that team project collection. However, In TFS 2017, it 's no longer possible to freely edit this field, and that you can only add a trigger for the team project that the build definition resides in.